# That's what make/makes the beautiful ‪‎rainbow‬

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

> That's what make/makes the beautiful ‪‎rainbow‬.

When we use "That's" which goes more appropriate with verb? 
In this case, "That's" with "make" or "makes"?
And why?

Answer (score 5):

*That* is a singular pronoun, so it requires a singular verb—*That **is***.

And since the pronoun *what*, which is the subject of *MAKE*, refers to *that*, it is also taken to be a singular entity, and therefore takes a singular verb—*What **makes***.

> Refraction of sunlight—***that is*** what **makes** the beautiful rainbow.

If you are speaking of several things which make the beautiful rainbow, you must use a plural pronoun at the beginning of the sentence:

> Sunlight and droplets of moisture in the air—***those are*** what **make** the beautiful rainbow.